# Storybook fails to parse JSX from directories imported from anywhere behind the root directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, storybook

I have a simple storybook project which is structured as so:

```
├── .storybook
├── .babelrc
├── package.json
├── node_modules
├── stories
│   ├── index.js
```

and I can run my config with `start-storybook -p 6006`

```
// .storybook/config.js
import { configure } from '@storybook/react'

function loadStories() {
  require('../stories/index.js')
}

configure(loadStories, module)
```

Now I want to include some components which are a directory behind. So the new file structure would be:

```
├── storybook
│   ├── .storybook
│   ├── .babelrc
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── node_modules
├── stories
│   ├── index.js
```

And my config now calls the stories from one directory back:

```
// ./storybook/.storybook/config.js
import { configure } from '@storybook/react'

function loadStories() {
  require('../../stories/index.js')
}

configure(loadStories, module)
```

but it seems storybook is unable to parse the file now, even though the only change is that the story has been moved on file back. I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ../admin-components/components/Button/Button.js 40:26
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (40:26)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from "react"
|
> const Button = (props) => <button>Click Me!!!</button>
|
| export default Button
 @ ../admin-components/components/Button/index.js 1:0-29 3:15-21
 @ ../admin-components/components/index.js
 @ ./stories/index.js
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/config/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/config/globals.js ./.storybook/config.js ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true
```

Do I need some custom parser config in my `.babelrc` or will this clash with the default storybook config. Perhaps there some setting for storybook to be able to handle this directory structure?

**EDIT**
Have tried adding further configuration to my webpack config to allow parsing of JSX but to no avail.

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (storybookBaseConfig, configType) => {
  storybookBaseConfig.resolve.alias = {
    'prop-types$': path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/axe-prop-types')
  };

  storybookBaseConfig.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: [/bower_components/, /node_modules/, /styles/],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../stories'),
        query: {
      presets: ['@babel/react']
    }
  });

  storybookBaseConfig.plugins.push(new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: '.storybook/fonts', to: 'fonts' }]))
  if (configType === 'PRODUCTION') {
    config.optimization.minimize = false;
  }

  return storybookBaseConfig;
}
```

getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./stories/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.
```

Comment: It is because the preset is called `@babel/preset-react`. Other than that - your approach should work just fine, as I am using a very similar setup to process modules by babel outside of `src` folder.

Comment: Where you able to resolve this?

Comment: I recommed running `yarn storybook --debug-webpack` (or `npm run storybook --debug-webpack`), as this will help see how things are set up.

Comment: i'm having exactly the same issue. any chance you got this solved?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you place each story in same folder where component declared❔

And then in storybook `config.js` file include them:

```js
import {configure} from '@storybook/react'

function loadStories() {
  const req = require.context(`../src`, true, /\.stories\.jsx?$/)
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename))
}

configure(loadStories, module)
```

Example of a story:

```js
import Icon from './index'
import React from 'react'
import {storiesOf} from '@storybook/react'

storiesOf(`Icons`, module)
  .add(`Bell`, () => (
    <Icon src="bell"/>
  ))
  .add(`Settings`, () => (
    <Icon src="settings"/>
  ))
  .add(`User`, () => (
    <Icon src="user"/>
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to **storybook/.storybook/webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.js?$/,
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../stories'),
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: './node_modules/.cache/storybook',
          presets: [
            [ './node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js',
              {
                shippedProposals: true, useBuiltIns: 'usage', corejs: '3'
              }
            ],
            './node_modules/@babel/preset-react/lib/index.js',
            './node_modules/@babel/preset-flow/lib/index.js',
          ],
          plugins: [],
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  config.resolve.modules = [
    ...config.resolve.modules,
    path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'node_modules'),
  ]

  // Return the altered config
  return config;
};
```

You **DO NOT NEED** to have .babelrc.

Explanation:
In this link: [Default config](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/default-config/), you can see the default configuration and I just copied some of the configs there. It will handle the approriate loader for your js/jsx.

As for the **config.resolve.modules**, you need to tell the webpack that your **node_modules** folder is not in the root directory in the stories so that when you use modules outside storybook folder, it will see the modules.

Hope this helps.